# Kali Linux 2.0 - Startup Text has disappeared

Tags: kali-linux, init

On Kali Linux 2, before you are greeted with the GUI login screen, there is some pre-GUI text that scrolls on the screen. It shows you what modules and programs are working correctly, which ones failed, etc.

Well, OpenVas always failed, so I did some commands to make it not fail, and now there is no text at all. That may or may not be the reason that the text is gone. I just know that it was there before, and is gone now.

So if you have any suggestions on how to get it back, please share.

Thanks

Comment: get the "some commands to make it not fail" back? Without knowledge what are your "some commands" it is really hard to say.

Comment: I used this [https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?27817-failed-to-start-open-vulnerability-assessment-system-scanner-daemon-in-kali-2-0-Plz-a](this) thread as reference, and followed the first answer's commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to edit the `/etc/default/grub` file: remove `quiet` from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. After that,  run `update-grub`.

Comment: Welcome to the Unix & Linux Stackexchange!

Comment: Yes, thank you I was busy rebooting and then forgot :)